# Подпись ajax запроса

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день.

Мне нужно защитить сайт так, чтобы нельзя было напряму обращаться к скриптам, а только через ajax.

Пока из решений только проверка `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`, но ее легко обойти.

Я вот и подумал - можно ли сделать какую нибудь подпись к запросу, и проверять ее на сервере?

Подскажите пожалуйста куда именно копать?

Comment: кука или сессия авторизировавшегося пользователя.

Comment: мой сайт без авторизации, и потом нет проблем запомниать куки и использовать их повторно темже `curl`

Comment: @DOC_tr, все, что может сделать пользователь через браузер, можно сделать либо через curl, либо через средства вроде phantomJS

Comment: Нельзя. Никуда.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но есть какие нибудь идеи, чтобы максимально затруднить отправку запросов не через ajax?

Comment: @DOC_tr, нету. AJAX запрос -- это обычный HTTP запрос. Между ними нет **никакой** разницы. Разве что, заголовок `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` да и тот запросто устанавливается через cURL.

Comment: Задача у вас странноватая и не знаю насколько это вас спасет, но попробуйте генерировать (на стороне сервера) уникальный ключ, который записываете в сессию и sessionStorage на клиенте. При отправке Ajax-запроса, добавляете этот ключ к остальным данным. В jQuery, например, это можно сделать в ajaxSetup, чтобы не прописывать в каждом запросе. cURL, насколько я знаю, к sessionStorage/localStorage доступа имееть не может. По поводу phantomJS - не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё раз предложу свою сырую идею защиты через **время** и **proof-of-work**.

Перед выполнением «рабочего» ajax запроса, делается запрос разрешения; в ответ сервер отдаёт какой-то уникальный JS код, требующий вычислений; код выполняется на клиенте и его результат служит «подписью» для рабочего ajax-запроса.

Сервер проверяет результат вычислений, и, главное, требует, чтобы время между запросом разрешения и запросом с результатом выполнения кода было минимально – исключая т.о. работу руками на стороне клиента.

Тут полно слабых мест: и плохой канал связи, при котором сайт перестанет работать, и возможность эмуляции всего и вся, и вероятность зловредного кода в качестве «задания». Но ведь не банковскую систему защищаем : )

Comment: ТС хочет верифицировать факт отправки запроса через AJAX, на не "напрямую к скриптам". Ваш метод защиты вполне можно обойти через curl. Т.е. -- не является ответом по сути.

Comment: На клиенте в паузе между двумя запросами – разрешающим и рабочим – должен будет выполниться JS-код, что в компании с curl реализуемо, но сложно.

Comment: Но вполне работает с phantomJS и прочими подобными решениями.

Comment: Ваше первое возражение сводилось к curl. Обойти такую защиту с PhantomJS или тем же nodejs конечно, можно, но требует навыков, которых нет у (навскидку) 98% пользователей системы ТС.